# match may not be exhaustive occurred when matching List

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

```
val l = 1::2::Nil
l match{ case x :: y:: Nil => println(x,y)}
```

a warning occurred when execute the above code segment:

```
<console>:12: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: List(_), List(_, _, _), Nil
       l match{ case x :: y:: Nil => println(x,y)}
       ^
(1,2)
```

But,`l match{ case List(x,y) => println(x,y)}`works well.
why?

Comment: To clarify @dk14's answer a bit: the last case doesn't _actually_ work well, it just fails to detect a possible error. To see this, change to e.g. `val l = 1 :: Nil`: there is still no warning, but it will fail at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::` is a case class (see [sources](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L439)). Case classes have automatic check for exhaustiveness (if inherited from sealed trait or sealed abstract class), so when you match `::(x, ::(y, Nil))` compiler can do that. See [this article](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/06/02/everything-about-sealed.html) for more info (keep in mind that case class is not precicely an ADT but they can model them).

`List(a,b)` just leads to calling `List.unapplySeq` from companion object (see [8.1.1 Extractor Patterns](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#extractor-patterns)), which means that compiler has no way to do additional check as it (simply saying) just transforms `case List(a,b)` into `unapplySeq` call.

Here is an example of total function which checks all possible inputs:

```
l match { 
  case a :: b :: Nil => Some(a + b)
  case _ => None    
}
```